# Consuming sharepoint 2010 claim-based WCF

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, project-server

I am trying to consume WCF based Sharepoint 2010 claim-based. I am getting the following error message: Thank you for any advice.

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException

"The content type text/html; charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 b..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get HTML from a web service, it means you're getting an error message. Look at the network traffic using Fiddler or something to see what the service is trying to tell you.